# Show $U_t(st)$ isomorphic to $U(s)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism

> Show $U_t(st)$ isomorphic to $U(s)$.

I've shown that the mapping $x \rightarrow x \pmod{s}$ is an injection of $U_t(st)$ into $U(s)$ where $U_t(st)=\{x\in U(st) \mid x \pmod{t}=1\}$ and $s$ and $t$ are coprime. I now want to show that this mapping is also a surjection by showing that $|U_t(st)|=|U(s)|$. I know that $|U(s)|=\phi(s)$, and I know $|U(st)|=\phi(s)\phi(t)$, but I’m not sure what else to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show by definition that the map $x \mapsto x \bmod{s}$ is surjective.

Let $y \in U(s)$. We want to find an $x \in U_t(st)$ such that $x$ should satisfy the following 3 properties:

1. $x \in U(st)$, same as saying that $\color{red}{\gcd(x,st)=1}$.
2. $\color{red}{x \equiv 1 \pmod{t}}$.
3. Of course, $\color{red}{x \equiv y\pmod{s}}$

---

**For $y \in U(s)$, now we construct such an $x$.**

Since $\gcd(s,t)=1$, so there $\exists \, a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$as+bt=1 \tag{1}$$
Let us define,
$$\color{magenta}{x':=y+sa(1-y)} \quad \text{ and } \quad \color{magenta}{x'=m(st)+x}, \quad \text{where }0 \leq x <st. $$
Then, $$\color{blue}{x' \equiv y \pmod{s}}. \tag{2}$$
Moreover we have
\begin{align*}
x'&=y+sa(1-y)\\
&=y+(1-bt)(1-y) & (\text{ from equ (1)})\\
&=1+t(by-b)\\
\color{blue}{x'} & \color{blue}{\equiv 1 \pmod{t}} \tag{3}.
\end{align*}
This means $\color{blue}{\gcd(x',t)=1}$. Suppose a prime $p \mid \gcd(x',s)$, then $y'$ being a linear combination of $x'$ and $s$ implies that $p \mid \gcd(y,s)$. But we know $y \in U(s)$, so $\gcd(y,s)=1$. Thus we have $\color{blue}{\gcd(x',s)=1}$ as well. Since $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime, so we can also claim that
$$\color{blue}{\gcd(x', st)=1}.$$
But $x$ being a linear combination of $x'$ and $st$ implies that $\color{blue}{\gcd(x,st)=1}$ as well. So we got our **condition 1**. From equation (3) and the definition of $x$, we also get $\color{blue}{x \equiv 1 \pmod{t}}$. So we have our **condition 2** as well. Lastly from the definition of $x$ and equation (2), we also get that $x \equiv y \pmod{s}$. This satisfies **condition 3**. So we have found our $x$. Thus the map is surjective.

Comment: You defined $x’$ twice - did you mean to define the first purple expression as $y’$?

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath I made a typo in using $:=$ in the second instance (I have corrected it). The second instance where $x'$ appears is basically to get $x$ from $x'$ (so I could have written that as $x:=x'-m(st)$). The idea is to define $x$ as the remainder of $x'$ when divided by $st$. This way we can make sure $x$ has all the good properties of $x'$ and is also $\leq st$.

Comment: That clarifies to me where you got the idea to define those two variables. I understand all of your proof - very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath Great. Thanks.